# DevForce Named query issue with includes on entities with inheritance

Tags: devforce

We observed an issue with a named query that is performing several includes on properties that are entities sharing the same base entity. As a picture is clearer, I made a simplified view of our model that I cannot publish here for some obvious reasons. Basically, we have a "TaskTarget" that is a base entity whose children are "Office" and "House". These two entity types are referenced by a Task entity.

Our problem occurs when we are trying to retrieve a set of Task entities by including House and Office. Basically, our named query is doing something like:

```
return new EntityQuery<Task>().Where(t => t.Id < 1000)
                   .Include(t => t.House)
                   .Include(t => t.Office);
```

We receive a list of tasks as expected but the House/Office are not correctly included. They remain null entities. We checked if the underlying query on the database (Oracle via DotConnect of Devart) was correct and that's the case with the appropriate joins, etc.

I don't know if a simple model such as the one depicted here is enough to exhibit the issue, our model is more complex of course but we had the feeling that the inheritance was the root of the issue as we did not had include issues when unrelated entities are involved.

The problem was observed in previous releases of DevForce, we tried with DevForce 2012 7.2.6 and it was still present.

[image]

Comment: Can you send your edmx, or the parts specific to these entities (including the storage and mapping models) to IdeaBlade support?  The type of inheritance could be a factor.  Also, since you're using a named query, can you show how your client is calling it?

Comment: I will send you the required info next week, thanks.